# Using Inkscape with Ubuntu (files on another partition)

Tags: partitioning, inkscape

Inkscape on Ubuntu works properly. However, if I try to open a `.svg` that is located on another partition, I get an error:

```
Failed to load the requested file /media/path/to/file.svg
```

Any idea what causes the problem and how to solve it?

**Bad walkaround**: I copy the file on the main partition of the OS and I work with it. After I copy it back. This solution messes up a bit the git repo I have and it is time-consuming.

Comment: Which file system does " another " partition use ? Were you able to mount it properly ? Can you play video files from " another " partition ? Which version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: (1) the ubuntu OS is on ext4. The partition I am speaking about is ntfs (it must be because it is shared with another Windows system. (2) the partition is mounted properly. (3) I can play video located on the ntfs partition with no problem. Also I can do many other things (from both the Linux based OS and Windows). I never had problems. (4) I am using Ubuntu 16.04. The problem arise only with Inkscape. All the other existing program on my Laptop does not give any error. Thank you for your question to claryfy the context!

Comment: Can you try by mounting the partition before opening Inkscape ?

Comment: in which sense? the partition is already mounted. If not I cannot double click on the file for example. As I said, the partition is mounted correctly and I have double-checked by `lsblk` with the command line. And yes, it is mounted BEFORE opening Inkscape

Comment: I was trying to say that make sure the partition is mounted before you start Inkscape. Is that the case now ? Do you mount first and then open Inkscape ?

Comment: yes, I mount first and after I open Inscape

Comment: Can try pasting a file into that directory which has the SVG files ?

Answer (score 3):

It would appear you've installed the snap version of inkscape which has no ability to use the removeable-media plugin so you're restricted to only opening files in $HOME. To check run this

```
snap list
```

If so either continue as you're presently doing if wanting to use the snap version, use the snap edge version or install the .deb version which has no restrictions.

The edge (dev) snap can be connected to removeable media though isn't by default. Maybe at some point the stable version will also get that possibility..
To do that,

```
sudo snap refresh inkscape --edge
```

Then connect to plugin

`snap connect inkscape:removable-media`

For the .deb version just,

```
 sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

You can keep both versions or remove the snap. The snap version is shown as Inkscape, the .deb as Inkscape Vector Graphics Editor though from context menu both are just inkscape..